# Is escaping only the last parameter in the query and ending the query with "--" safe?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, code-injection

I am thinking of practical solutions for this escaping methods. mysql_query doesn't make two queries at once so the attacker can't use things like ' OR 1; delete from user; select * from //he would guess the rest of the query here. (it becomes confusing)

(I obviously don't like pdo, it is not practical in oop when you need to define a connection in each function of each class, otherwise I have to use $this or global $dbc each time.)

Comment: On the contrary, PDO makes OOP really nice. My guess is that you are not using a very convenient OO setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. There are multiple ways that a query can be "unsafe", besides burying a separate DML or DDL or statement. For example:

- A large, very-poorly-performing subquery could be used to bring your database to a crawl.
- A branch of the WHERE-clause could invoke an arbitrary stored procedure, with whatever effects that might have.

and every specific query would have to be vetted for the possibility of random code being inserted in the middle. For example, if the query results will somehow be presented to the user, then a subquery pointing at a table with authentication information could potentially let the user infer a great deal. (Imagine a series of tests `where exists (select 1 from app_users where username = 'JoeAdmin' and password like 'a%')`, then `password like 'ba%'` once the `b` is identified, and so on. Even if the hacker doesn't initially know that you have a table named `app_users`, they can quickly figure that out by using this sort of approach on system tables.)

Comment: @LeviMorrison: I think I was right to make it an answer rather than a comment, but wrong to phrase it as a series of rhetorical questions rather than as a straightforward "no".

Comment: @LeviMorrison: O.K., thanks for your input. I've changed it to be answer-ier now.

Answer (score 2):

The practical solution to escaping is this:

```
$blah = mysql_real_escape_string($blah, $connection);
$num = (int)$num;
$sql = "select * from `test` where foo = '$blah' and num_col = $num";
```

Any time you insert a variable into an SQL string, it needs to be escaped. With no exceptions. You should do this escaping as close as possible to the point where it's embedded, to make it easier to verify that this is taking place when proof reading your code.

If you only ever have one single connection, you might define your own function:

```
function qescape($var)
{
  global $connection;
  return mysql_real_escape_string($var, $connection);
}
```

I take a big issue with this statement you made:

> mysql_query doesn't make two queries at once so the attacker can't use things like

While technically true, they can do all kinds of other nasty things without any need to run multiple queries. A good hacker probably will be able to view and modify and insert virtually anything they want in your database, even without being able to run multiple queries.

Answer (score 2):

No, you still need to escape every non-numeric type, not just the last parameter.

Example for checking if a username / password match should log in a user:

```
// Check username / password
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = 'nickb' AND password = 'password'
```

If only the last parameter is escaped (password), then I can pass this:

- `username="nickb' --"`

Resulting in:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = 'nickb'
```

Here, the user gets logged in with no password necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the whole idea.

Why you came to such a method?
There are regular methods of escaping/binding/whitelisting.
Why none of them suits you? Why to devise something unusual and unusable?

I told you many times already - escaping is not something "to protect from injection".
It is just a part of SQL syntax rules. And only as a side effect it protects your strings from injection.
So, you have to escape (if you don't want to bind) your strings anyway.
So, there is no use for such a strange inventions like "escaping only the last parameter in the query" **at all**.

Got the idea?